# Flickr authentication with mobile webview stopped working

Tags: android, flickr

Recently Flickr OAuth authentication stopped working. The app is for Android and I use Flick4Java for the Flick API and authentication.

The flow follows the guideline here https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html so we get the request token and show the Flickr authentication screen in the WebView.

The user can enter the user id (email in Flickr) and password is verified but Webview see no shouldOverrideUrlLoading() calls after sign in as it used to happen.

Any idea what has been changed or how to show the webview to catch the oauth_verifier?

Answer (score 1):

The webview seems's to require another setting to work with Flickr oauth.

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```